# Field padding while dropping commas and decimal in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a formula field in Crystal Report XI that takes a monetary/numeric field and converts it to 10 characters with preceding zeroes, while dropping any commas or decimals. For example: 2,907.41 becomes 0000290741. Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`totext(({table.number}*100),"0000000000")`